# in bash how do I loop through directories starting with "abc" and the directory "special-dir"

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have this code:

```
for dir in abc*/ ; do
    echo $dir
done
```

This works, but I have one special directory (lets say its called "special-dir"). How can I add that to my loop, I am thinking somthing like:

```
for dir in abc*/ + "special-dir" ; do
    echo $dir
done
```

Obvously that does not work!, but I can't quite think how to do this.

Comment: Drop the + and you are good to go.

Comment: @Socowi ahhh... sweet :)  .. if you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it up

Comment: Thanks. There's already an answer here, so I pass.

Comment: @Socowi ok, yours was first (just), but thanks anyway : )

Comment: Please, allow us to Google that for you: [bash loop over multiple directories site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+loop+over+multiple+directories+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @jww I did look around on google. Didn't use that phrasing - I was looking for things like "loop with directories starting with x as well as full names". So in the end I decided to ask people with more experience then me to give me some pointers... or to use their experience to show a google link with better search... both are perfectly valid in my view. I just lacked the knowledge / experience to find the answer myself... if you want to have a go at me for being dumb/inexperienced... well, that's your thing, but I find that quite sad : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path expansion just expands the glob to list of the actual directories. Word list is space separated, so just use space to separate the next element of the list:

```
for dir in abc*/ special-dir ; do
    echo "$dir"
done
```